# SWIFT and EventKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Hey guys i'm new to swift and Events Kit, i got this line of code can i possibly be able to print events from it and not calendar names?

```
    var eventStore = EKEventStore()
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent,
        completion: {(granted: Bool, error:NSError!) in
            if !granted {
                println("Access to store not granted")
            }
    })

    let events = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent)

    for events in events as [EKCalendar] {
        println("events = \(events.title)")

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that I know of to get the events from an EKEventStore, however they both require a predicate, usually using a start/end date and an array of calendars to check.

```
let predicate = store.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: nil) // nil calendar checks all calendars, otherwise pass [EKCalendar]
```

Use:

```
let events = store.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate) as [EKEvent]
```

Or:

```
store.enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate(predicate) { event, stop in

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, sorry to bother you again but i created a searchPredicate for the calendar and it works when there are event in the calendar, when theres nothing it gives me errors you can check my code in my profile thanks

Comment: @HenryEdwards can't you just add an if statement to check that there are events in the calendar, if there aren't, return?  ... if events.count == 0 { store.enumerateEv.....   } else { print("No events"); return